# Best way to go about "HiPot" testing setup

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, systems-engineering

What is the best way to set up a dielectric strength test?  I am planning on using two threaded copper rods for adjustable movement that will receive the voltage.  In between the two rods will be the dielectric (wafer/thin film).  Any insight on how to create a platform for testing consisting of two copper rods and a place to put the dielectric would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about dielectric strength Testing? The question as stated is very broad.

Comment: I have a good understating of the technicalities.  I am more concerned on how to create a physical setup to conduct HIPOT test  on a small wafer/film.  I was thinking of using Copper threaded rods that will receive the voltage.  In between the two rods will be the dielectric, but am not sure how to hold the dielectric or what material should be used to place the dielectric (wafer or thin film).